# How do I install OBS Studio on 14.10?

Tags: software-installation, 14.10

As FFMPEG is not "officially" supported on 14.10, how do I install it?

I'm trying to get OBS Studio to work on 14.10, and FFMPEG is a dependency I cannot satisfy...

Comment: Do you intend to compile OBS Stutio from source or have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to get FFmpeg, but I am not familiar with OBS so I'm not sure what its exact requirements are.

## Download

The simplest method is to [download a static build of the `ffmpeg` binary](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). If OBS only wants the binary this could work. If it needs the libraries you will need to compile or use a PPA.

You may have to place the binary somewhere in your `$PATH` for OBS to recognize it, or perhaps manually tell OBS where it is.

## PPA

mc4man provides recent `ffmpeg` binaries via his PPA: [Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media). I believe this provides support for libfdk_aac (an execellent AAC audio encoder) while the static build I mentioned previously does not. Libraries are not included.

[Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg) provides older FFmpeg branches to be compatible with dependencies in the repository.

## Compile

Step-by-step, non-intrusive compilation instructions are available at [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). The guide "installs" within your home directory so it does not interfere with the system; binaries into `~/bin` and libraries and other stuff into `~/ffmpeg_build`.

---

#### Required Version

OBS may require a certain version or release of FFmpeg if it is not compatible with the current git master of FFmpeg. If this is the case you can compile any version you need. Follow the compile guide, but after cloning the repository with `git clone` run `git tag` to list branch versions, then `git checkout <tag name>`. To go back to the master branch run `git checkout master`.

#### The Return of the King

FFmpeg will be back in Ubuntu in 15.04.